# C#: Thread.Join() freezes UI

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

I would like to gracefully stop an endlessly looping thread from running whenever a button is clicked. Here's what as I understand should work:

```
bool running = true;

private Thread myThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(threadWorker));

private void threadWorker()
{
    while(running)
    {
        ...
    }
}

private void button_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    running = false
    myThread.Join();
    ...
}
```

However clicking the button freezes the UI thread. Pausing the program to debug shows it stuck on Thread.Join(). If I put the "running" flag on a separate button and click it before joining then it works fine, but this way it's is as if the flag is never changed ant the method never ends.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:** This question is NOT a duplicate of "Why is CPU usage constantly increasing after starting/stopping threads?", adding "volatile" to the flag declaration did not solve the problem.

In my case the program was freezing at the UI update invokes (thanks to usr for telling me I can check what the other threads are doing). Replacing `Control.Invoke` with `Control.BeginInvoke` solved the problem.

Comment: Have you tried debugging your worker loop?

Comment: I am quite new at this, how exactly would I carry on with debugging the worker? I am using Visual Studio 2015 Community. "Break all" while it is frozen shows me it being stuck on myThread.Join() with the "running" flag being false, as it should.

Comment: @IhavenoideawhatI'mdoing use the threads windows to switch to the other thread. It's busy and not exiting. That's why Join does not complete.

Comment: Not sure what I should switch to.

Comment: There are at least two thread. Switch to the other one so that you can see its stack. need to investigate what threadWorker is doing.

Comment: Ah, I see. The worker thread seems to be stuck at an invoke to update a chart. Not sure why it is stuck, though.

Comment: I don't get that dupe closure at all. No relatedness at all.

Comment: Me neither. Replacing Invoke with BeginInvoke solved it for me. Still don't completely understand why it froze, though. Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: See my answer, in case you didn't notice it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The worker thread seems to be stuck at an invoke to update a chart.

The worker tries to access the UI thread through an invoke. But the UI is stuck waiting in the `Join`. It's a deadlock.

`Thread` in conjunction with UI is obsolete. Switch to using `await` and such problems go away.

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't mention otherwise, I suppose `running` is not declared `volatile` which means `threadWorker()` method doesn't check it's "real" value, but a cached value of it. Try declaring it as

```
volatile bool running;
```

Comment: You are right, I did not declare it as volatile. However adding volatile did not help, the UI still freezes.